# Bad triage test question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

I got this question [Array vs. list data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580177/array-vs-list-data-type) while working on Triaging questions.

I voted to close as "too broad".

> STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit, designed to see if you were
>   paying attention. You didn't pass. This question is clear and
>   answerable. While there may be minor flaws, it Looks OK.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

It is neither clear nor provides enough informations to answer it - as is. One would have to follow the link to get down to "what distinction pearl 5 does to array and list data types" - that one is a good one. This question though does not provide *at all* enough information to answer it (IMHO).

Comment: fixed. shouldn't be used as an audit anymore. A single downvote is enough to make it not eligible, or you can edit it to make it a good question, though i'd err on the side of not doing that in this case.

Comment: I must've missed where it was "too broad".  It seems like it's narrow, objective, and entirely answerable for any reasonable Perl expert.  Am I not seeing something you and @KevinB are?

Comment: I don't think it's too broad, it's just not what i would consider to be a question that "Looks Ok". Referencing the original question is fine, but it should have included enough of it in the question itself as to not rely on it.

Comment: @KevinB:  I mildly disagree.  To me this reads objectively and plainly, and has the feeling of being answerable by someone who actually knows Perl.  Nitpicking this question even though in its present state it's *plenty* answerable makes this a false positive in the audit queue.  At best I can agree to disagree here; I'm not seeing anything here that wouldn't make me think this question isn't okay.

Comment: If anything it's just a bad audit, that doesn't necessarily make it a bad question. It was a question with questionable quality but apparently above average usefulness and/or interest.

Comment: I think I disagree with the  stance that the audit is bad, too.  All audits can do is see if you're genuinely paying attention, so the vast majority of them simply throw garbage at you to see if you're a human behind the machine.   This audit actually *required* you to stop and think about this question.  That's *rare*.  I wish this were still an audit question.

Comment: It is one of the ways an audit is constructed, it picked a Q+A with 21 helpful votes.  Not seeing that and voting to destroy it is always an audit fail.  The "look" part in the stop message applies.  Some users demand to vote to destroy anyway, on principle, I don't think they last long.

Comment: @HansPassant The audit-questions do not show theire answers, just the questions. I could open the question outside of Triage and check if it an audit case that was answered - but in general I go for what I get presented. I saw no specific question, (Arrays vs Lists - for what purpose?) - a link to some other question and a "does p6 make the same distinction". For me there was not enough "meat on the bone" - my take away is: I will rather skip then closevote if the topic is about smth I am not familar with. At least now I am more aware how Audits are choosen and why there might be poor ones in.

Comment: Well, you learned that you just can't rely on the review page by itself.  Yes, it is flawed.  And yes, you have learn that it is only a hint to go explore more.  Rather the point of audits.